# trying to solve for mean and standard deviation using Normcumdist and Solve

Tags: equation-solving, probability-or-statistics

I am trying to find values for the mean and standard deviation of a normal distribution with these characteristics.

$\qquad P(X \le 90) = 0.96$

$\qquad P(X \le 50) = 0.3$

I am trying to do this using `Normcumdist` and `Solve`. Here is what I have so far, `x` is the mean and `y` is the standard deviation.

`Solve[N[Normalcumdist[90, x, y]] == 0.96, {x, y}]`

Unfortunately, this doesn't work.

Does anyone have any advice?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]
```

The distribution is

```
dist = NormalDistribution[mu, sigma];

eqns = {CDF[dist, 90] == 0.96, CDF[dist, 50] == 0.3};

param = Solve[eqns, {mu, sigma}][[1]] // Quiet

(* {mu -> 59.2199, sigma -> 17.5817} *)
```

Verifying,

```
eqns /. param

(* {True, True} *)
```

Graphically,

```
Plot @@
 ({CDF[dist, x], {x, mu - 3 sigma, mu + 3 sigma},
    Epilog -> {Red, Dashed,
      Line[{{90, 0}, {90, CDF[dist, 90]}, {mu - 3 sigma, CDF[dist, 90]}}],
      Line[{{50, 0}, {50, CDF[dist, 50]}, {mu - 3 sigma, CDF[dist, 50]}}]},
    AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 12, Bold] & /@
       {x, CDF}),
    PlotLabel -> Style[dist, 12, Bold]} /. param)
```

[image]