# using exponential distribution to solve a half life problem

Tags: probability-or-statistics

i have information about the half life of a certain element. the half life is 29 years.

i need to calculate how much of this material is left if we start counting from 1954, which was 66 years ago.

i have been told that i need to solve for the mean of the cumulative exponential distribution so that i can construct the exponential distribution for the life of this material. and then i guess i use this together with the exponential distribution to see how much is left after 66 years.

this is my attempt to solve for mu:

`Solve[Exponentialcumdist[29, mu] == 1/2, mu]`

unfortunately this returns an insane non-real result. i don't understand why i can't use this approach, because if i substitute letters for the arguments i get a sensible result.

i think i'm supposed to take the result once i find it and plug it into `Exponentialcumdist[]` together with `t = 66` to find the final answer that i'm looking for. but i am stuck on this programming bug.

any advice for how to solve for a real value of `mu`? thank you in advance for any insight.

Comment: In response to an [`earlier question`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/233968/9362) you were given an example how to use Mathematica's built-in distribution functions. Why do you continue to try to use non-existent functions?

Comment: @BobHanlon i guess i am using some kind of mathematica based software that has slightly different syntax. the solution you offered last time did work for me once i adapted it though.

Comment: If you want help with using some specialized package you need to identify what package and how to access it. However, I recommend that you just use standard Mathematica functions since they do what you appear to be trying to accomplish.

Comment: To get a real result from `Solve` either specify the domain as `Reals` or include the constraint `mu > 0`

Comment: This looks like homework. Is it? If so, please tag it as such.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the exponential decay formula.

```
n[t_] = n0 E^(-λ t)
```

where n0 is the initial amount of material.  It could be mass or atoms. the λ is the exponential scaling exponent.

```
thalf = 29
```

Find λ in terms of the half life.

```
n[thalf] == n0/2
(*E^(-29 λ) n0 == n0/2*)
```

Solve for λ.

```
Solve[%, λ, Reals] // Flatten
(*{λ -> Log[2]/29}*)
```

Then solve for the amount after 66 years.

```
n[66] // N
(*0.206489 n0*)
```

Just less than 21% of the original amount.

Answer (score 1):

In ***Mathematica***:

```
hl = 29;
dist = ExponentialDistribution[Log[2]/hl];
1. - CDF[dist, 66]
```

> 0.206489

So, ~20%.

This is the second question from you using non-Mathematica functions in the OP. Please provide in the future the full definitions of any such thing in you OP, or better yet, perhaps use the fora for the particular software you are using.